# codeigniter .htaccess works fine in localhost server but not in web server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

.htaccess works fine in my xampp server but when I uploaded it to the web server, it gives me this error"404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found."

here are my configs.

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

and my .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I place my codeigniter in a subfolder /sibulanAdmin
http://sibulanlgu.spillworks.net/sibulanAdmin/

This cost me a lot of time searching in the web, but no solutions works for me.
please help

Comment: Did you try `RewriteBase /sibulanAdmin/`?

Comment: yes, but it doesnt work. Did I missing something?

Comment: Be sure server is not windows.

Comment: Could you find a sollution? I've the same problem here

Answer (score 0):

As your provided information, your .htaccess should be like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /sibulanAdmin/index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Make sure mod rewrite is enable on your server. If not yet, you should follow on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) answer and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite) tutorial. Hope it will be work for you.

**Edit**

You can enable mod rewrite by typing in terminal like that :

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

And then, don't forget to set `AllowOverride` to `all` of document root in your apache configuration. In your apache2.conf, (`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` in my case)

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Finally, just need to restart your server.

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I tried this code, but still not working. As I checked, mod_rewrite was not enabled. I also tried the two links you recommend. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this htaccess below, it works for me I have xampp and works fine on live server

And Change

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

To

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

**htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: May be start with fresh copy of codeigniter from http://www.codeigniter.com/download and / or then go to here http://www.insiderclub.org/downloads and you can download some htaccess files there. But once added htacces in main directory then go and make `$config['index_page'] = '';` like so